# Variable keeps returning as nil what is the reason?

Tags: lua, roblox

giant_player keeps returning as nil even though it gets it reference from the random function
what could be the problem?

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local players = Players:GetPlayers()

wait(10)

for i = #players, 2, -1 do
    local j = math.random(i)
    players[i], players[j] = players[j], players[i]
end

local giant_player = players[1]

print(giant_player)

giant_player.TeamColor = BrickColor.new("Bright red")
giant_player.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 50
giant_player.Character.Humanoid.JumpPower = 100
giant_player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Size = Vector3.new(6, 12, 6)

for _, player in ipairs(players) do
    if player == giant_player then
        player:Chat("You are the giant!")
    else
        player:Chat(giant_player.Name .. " is the giant!")
    end
end

for _, player in pairs(players) do

    if player == giant_player then
        player.CameraMaxZoomDistance = 100
        player.CameraMinZoomDistance = 10
        player.CameraHeight = 20
        player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CanCollide = true
        player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Size = Vector3.new(6, 12, 6)
        player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CustomPhysicalProperties = PhysicalProperties.new(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1, 1)
        player.Character.HumanoidRootPart:ClearAllChildren()
    else
        player.CameraMaxZoomDistance = 25
        player.CameraMinZoomDistance = 5
        player.CameraHeight = 5
    end
```

The purpose of the script is to find a random player in the player list and make them into a giant

Comment: What is `#players`? The doc always uses pairs to iterate, are you sure players is an array?

Comment: @Luke100000 `Players:GetPlayers()` returns an array of Players. `pairs` works just as well as `ipairs` with an array. But in this case, it is almost certain that `#players` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to randomize that way? I would just use math.random with the range. You're possibly messing up the players table with it with your for loop. I haven't tested but this should select a random player from the list for you.

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local players = Players:GetPlayers()

wait(10)

local giant_player = players[math.random(1, #players)]

print(giant_player)
```